# Grid Arrange Network Maps

Tags: r, gridextra

I have used the `igraph package` to draw 11 different network maps. I would like to arrange them in the same page (say 4x3) like what the `grid.arrange` function does. But the `grid.arrange` function only works with `grob` objects.

Is there away for me to achieve the above, not necessarily using the `grid.arrange` function but just a way to panel the network maps in the same page.

or alternatively is it possible to change the `igraph` objects to `grob` objects that the `grid.arrange` function can work with?

The following produces four star networks just as a sample code;

```
library(igraph)
library(gridExtra)
g1 <- graph.ring(10)
g2 <- graph.ring(12)
g3 <- graph.ring(13)
grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3), 1, 3, byrow = TRUE))
plot(g1)
plot(g2)
plot(g3)
```

[image]

**[Edit: taking into account OP's comment]**

```
m <- matrix(c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(3,10), rep(4,6), rep(5,6), rep(6,6), rep(7,6), rep(8,6), rep(9,10), rep(10,10), rep(11,10)), 3, 30, byrow=TRUE)
nf <- layout(m)
layout.show(nf)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Pascal. What if the number of plots is not a multiple of the number of rows?

Comment: I think you should check `?layout`, particularly the use of `0` as index.

Comment: Like the result that I would like to have is with the first 3 plots in the same row, the next 5 plots in row 2, and the last 3 in row 3. This is because the first 3 maps are subsets of the same region, the next 5 subsets of the second region and the last 3 are also subsets of the same region. This is just desired for visual comparability of the plots.